# error: Package `use-package-' is unavailable

Tags: init-file, use-package, docker, emacs-nox

I am starting to build up a .emacs file to be used as a development environment within Docker containers.  I get this error when starting emacs-nox in a Docker container.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/root/.emacs':

error: Package `use-package-' is unavailable
```

Here is the contents of my .emacs

```
;; require package
(require 'package)

;; add melpa stable
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))

;; add melpa
(add-to-list 'package-archives
         '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))

;; Initialise packages
(package-initialize)

;; add use package
(package-install 'use-package)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This particular error happens if Emacs failed looking up the latest version of a package, like if there's no package-archives file containing that information.  Before installing packages, make sure to run `M-x package-refresh-contents` so that there is one.  Alternatively, use `M-x package-list-packages` for installing packages, that ensures that the package-archives files are up to date.

Comment: This helped me get it working.  I added (package-refresh-contents) to my .emacs file after (package-initialize) and before (package-install 'use-package).

Comment: Comments risk being deleted at any time. Consider moving your comment to an answer.

Comment: This helped ; you may have to do [this too](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51772/6701) afterwards.

Answer (score 9):

I am adding this answer as suggested by @Drew.

I appreciate the answer from @wasamasa which allowed me to get this working in my .emacs file.

Here is how I modified my .emacs file.

```
(package-initialize)

(package-refresh-contents)

(package-install 'use-package)
```

Comment: This helped me to realize that I erroneously tried to double quote the package name.

Comment: FYI,  this will cause `emacs` to refresh the list during each launch. Consider adding a conditional, e.g. `(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))` to avoid reloading your package list each time. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24280417/9161344