# Melpa - 'Failed to download melpa'

Tags: debugging, list

I am on a fresh install of emacs 26.3, and I have the following in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa", "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

When I go to refresh the package list (`M-x package-refresh-contents`) I encounter the following error:

```
  string-match("\\`https?:" ((\, "http://melpa.org/packages/")) nil)
  package--download-one-archive(("melpa" (\, "http://melpa.org/packages/")) "archive-contents" t)
  package--download-and-read-archives(t)
  package-refresh-contents(t)
  package-menu-refresh()
  package-list-packages(nil)
  funcall-interactively(package-list-packages nil)
  call-interactively(package-list-packages record nil)
  command-execute(package-list-packages record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "package-list-packages" "package-lis")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "package-list-packages" "package-lis")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

What is happening and why doesn't this work? I have seen [some chatter](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51721/failed-to-download-gnu-archive) on related issues that

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```

before `(package-initialize)` should resolve this issue, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error seems to be saying that `((\, "http://melpa.org/packages/"))` doesn't match the regex

```
"\`https?:"
```

Let's look at that value, the one being added to `package-archives`:

```
'("melpa", "http://melpa.org/packages/")
```

If we put this into `IELM`, let's see what we get:

```
ELISP> '("melpa", "http://melpa.org/packages/")
("melpa"
 (\, "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

Oh! This is not what we expect! The `cdr` of this list is a proper list (we want a string), and *that* has a comma as the first character.

What happened here? What is each element of `package-archives` supposed to be?

> package-archives is a variable defined in ‘package.el’.
>
> Each element has the form (ID . LOCATION).

A period instead of a comma makes this a single cons cell, and not a proper list. The proper code is:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
```

Comment: Thank you, correct syntax is good to have :/