# fresh install on raspberry pi can't download "gnu" archive

Tags: package-repositories

Raspberry Pi, Model 4, everything up to date with Raspberry Pi OS.
I execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt install emacs (verson 26.1)

mkdir .emacs.d

emacs
```

then

`M-x package-refresh-contents`

which gives the error message:

`Failed to download the gnu archive`

I have tried a couple of things from these links:

[Failed to download 'gnu' archive](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51721/failed-to-download-gnu-archive)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108655/error-updating-emacs-packages-failed-to-download-gnu-archive

But I haven't gotten anything to succeed yet.

Comment: What does `C-h v package-archives RET` say?

Comment: Have to check later, but initially I had set the package-archives to the standard options for elpa and melpa: `https://melpa.org/#/getting-started`, I was able to pull packages from melpa, but not from elpa

Comment: Make sure it contains an entry like this: `("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")`.

Comment: `(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/"))`, just checked

Comment: What's the emacs version? If it is 26.3 or so, I would try the `(setq package-set-signature nil)` method (from your second link).

Comment: emacs version is `26.1`  That's what is available from the archive for the ppa

Answer (score 2):

If you're running an emacs version earlier than 26.3 (like 26.1), try `(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")`.

If that works then you're hitting a bug in Emacs that was fixed in 26.3.

Comment: This worked for me. Emacs version was 26.1.